# URL redirect in Chrome webRequest for blocked URLs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url, redirect, google-chrome-extension

I am creating an extension that redirects certain sites to a local extension page. In a few cases, I'd like the user to be able to go to the actual site, based on a URL parameter I add to the extension page.
So the flow is:

1. User goes to 'cnn.com'
2. They are redirected to my extension page, which has a few links, like:    `cnn.com/story/page/text?showRealUrl=true`
3. When they click on this 'special' link, I want to take them to the real URL:    `cnn.com/story/page/text`

Here's my code:

```
const approved = '?showRealUrl=true';
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function swenNewsListener (details) {
        var i = 0;
            if (details.url.endsWith(approved) ) {
                i = i + 1; 
                var u = details.url.replace(approved, '')
                console.log(i + " actual URL: " + u );
                return { redirectUrl: u }; // this doesn't seem to work
            } else {
                console.log(i + " in ext mode");
                var baseUrl = new URL(details.url).hostname.split(".").slice(-2).join(".")
                return { redirectUrl: chrome.extension.getURL("markup/articleList.html?sourceUrl=" + baseUrl) };
            }
    },
    { urls: ["*://*.cnn.com/*"] },  
    ["blocking"]
);
```

But the console output is:

```
1 actual URL: https://cnn.com/story/page/text
0 in ext mode
```

And it takes me right back to the extension page instead of the real URL.

How do I get around this?

Comment: Judging by the console output `u` is an invalid URL because it doesn't have protocol like `https://`

Comment: Sorry, i typed the output by hand - fixed it now. `u` is a valid URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There didn't seem to be a straightforward way to do this, so I ended up removing the listener when I wanted to go to the actual website, and then I re-add the listener when the `onCompleted` event fires.